# Spring boot redirect webapp static resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having problens to make a correct static mapping in Spring boot.

Resourses Problem:

[image]

I have to redirect every request for "/scripts" or "/styles" for "/app/styles|scripts".

Current the code is like this:

```
@Override  
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/swagger").setViewName("redirect:/swagger/");
    registry.addViewController("/swagger/").setViewName("forward:/swagger/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/webapp/");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/webapp/index.html");

    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);  
}
```

I also tryed to put

```
registry.addViewController("/script").setViewName("redirect:/webapp/script/");
registry.addViewController("/style").setViewName("redirect:/webapp/style/");
```

But I got the same error. I need to have the webapp in a diferent folder because its is aute generated.

Comment: put your style/ folder in `src/main/resources/static`

Comment: I can do, but I don't want to, I have the swagger folder (could be deletede in the future if the i use the front-end build directly). So I would like to have `/static/swagger` (all the swagger-ui html stuff) and `/static/webapp` (here I will have my app, and its ok if I delete and create again the folder)

Comment: Your requests are looking for scripts and styles and you have added viewControllers with /script and /style. You can try changing that.